# How to Avoid very long time python calculations while iterating through pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to add 2 columns to dataframe to calculate vehicle surroundings neighbor 50 and neighbor 100 for each vehicle in each direction and in each time frame based on distance, if distance below 50 I add one count to the neighbor 50 and so on, I should do this task using Pandas only

I should calculate distance based on x and y position of each vehicle through the equation:

distance = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**0.5

I have used this code:

```
#import numpy as np

df['neighbor_50'] = 0
df['neighbor_100'] = 0
frame_group =  df.groupby(['frame','direction'])
list_keys = list(frame_group.indices.keys())

for key in list_keys :
    frame , direction = key[0] , key[1]
    #new_df =  df.loc[(df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction)]
    mask1 = (df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction) 
    ids = df[mask1]['id']
    for i in ids:
        for j in ids:
            if i != j:
                #distance = sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
                maski = (df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction)& (df['id'] == i)
                maskj = (df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction)& (df['id'] == j)
                x2 = df[maski]['x'].iloc[0]
                x1 = df[maskj]['x'].iloc[0]
                y2 = df[maski]['y'].iloc[0]
                y1 = df[maskj]['y'].iloc[0]
                
                distance = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**0.5
                #distance = np.hypot((x2 - x1),(y2 - y1))
                mask = (df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction) &( df['id']== i)
                if distance <= 50:
                    df.loc[mask , 'neighbor_50'] += 1
                if distance <= 100 :
                    df.loc[mask ,'neighbor_100'] += 1
```

the problem is that it takes forever to complete because the data is big even when i use NumPy.

input sample
[image: input sample]

output sample
[image]

update:
I have managed to reduce the time by half by avoiding repeating calculations for same ids , but still so slow

```
import numpy as np

df['neighbor_50'] = 0
df['neighbor_100'] = 0
frame_group =  df.groupby(['frame','direction'])
list_keys = list(frame_group.indices.keys())

for key in list_keys :
    frame , direction = key[0] , key[1]
    #new_df =  df.loc[(df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction)]
    mask = (df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction) 
    ids = df[mask]['id'].values
    for i in range(len(ids)-1):
        id1 = ids[i]
        for j in range(i+1,len(ids)):
            id2 = ids[j]
            
            maski = (df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction)& (df['id'] == id1)
            maskj = (df['frame'] == frame) & (df['direction'] == direction)& (df['id'] == id2)
            x2 = df[maski]['x'].iloc[0]
            x1 = df[maskj]['x'].iloc[0]
            y2 = df[maski]['y'].iloc[0]
            y1 = df[maskj]['y'].iloc[0]
            
            #distance = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**0.5
            distance = np.hypot((x2 - x1),(y2 - y1))
           
            if distance <= 100 :
                df.loc[maski ,'neighbor_100'] += 1
                df.loc[maskj ,'neighbor_100'] += 1
                
                if distance <= 50:
                    df.loc[maski , 'neighbor_50'] += 1
                    df.loc[maskj , 'neighbor_50'] += 1
```

Comment: Can you share a sample input and output?

Comment: please check the inputs and outputs

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible code which can be used to calculate the euclidean distance that you want from the above dataframe? This problem can be solved using simple series operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, but this is probably the fastest without using `scipy` or `numpy`:

```py
import pandas

# Only for generation of test data
import random
import itertools

# Only for debugging (shows progress bar)
from tqdm import tqdm

tqdm.pandas()


# Generate some realistic looking test data
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        [
            [
                {
                    "id": int(identifier),
                    "frame": frame,
                    "direction": random.randint(0, 1),
                    "x": random.random() * random.randint(-100, 100),
                    "y": random.random() * random.randint(-100, 100),
                }
                for frame in range(50)
            ]
            for identifier in range(100)
        ]
    )
)


def get_neighbor_count(group: pandas.DataFrame) -> pandas.DataFrame:
    """ Function that gets the number of neighbors within a certain distance (50 and 100 units) and
    in the same direction.

    Args:
        group (pandas.DataFrame): The input dataframe (all IDs within the same timeframe)

    Returns:
        pandas.DataFrame: The same dataframe with the number of neighbors
    """

    # Cartesian product of self (join the full dataframe with itself)
    group["key"] = 0
    group["index"] = group.index
    group_cartesian = group.merge(group, on="key", suffixes=("", "_target",)).drop(
        columns=["key"]
    )

    # Filter out combinations with self (distance == 0)
    group_cartesian = group_cartesian.loc[
        group_cartesian["id"] != group_cartesian["id_target"]
    ]

    # Only consider combinations in the same direction
    group_cartesian = group_cartesian.loc[
        group_cartesian["direction"] == group_cartesian["direction_target"]
    ]

    # Calculate the distances between the points (your function: distance = ((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)**0.5)
    group_cartesian["distance"] = (
        (group_cartesian["x_target"] - group_cartesian["x"]) ** 2
        + (group_cartesian["y_target"] - group_cartesian["y"]) ** 2
    ) ** 0.5

    # Set the index (needed for matching the results back to the group)
    group_cartesian = group_cartesian.set_index("index")

    # Select the rows with less than 50 or less than 100
    within_50 = group_cartesian.loc[group_cartesian["distance"] <= 50]
    within_100 = group_cartesian.loc[group_cartesian["distance"] <= 100]

    # Count the number of found neighbors
    neighbor_50 = within_50.groupby(["index"])["id_target"].count()
    neighbor_100 = within_100.groupby(["index"])["id_target"].count()

    # Add the new series to the group
    group = pandas.concat(
        [group, neighbor_50.rename("neighbor_50"), neighbor_100.rename("neighbor_100")],
        axis=1,
    )

    # Return the group
    return group


df = df.groupby("frame").progress_apply(get_neighbor_count).droplevel(0).sort_index()
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
100%|██████████| 50/50 [00:01<00:00, 45.30it/s]
      id  frame  direction          x          y  key  index  neighbor_50  \
0      0      0          1   1.154344  10.168371    0      0         30.0   
1      0      0          1  11.581348  -2.878279    0      1         33.0   
2      0      0          1  -3.577821  -0.989225    0      2         31.0   
3      0      0          1 -39.239073 -21.107833    0      3         20.0   
4      0      0          1 -30.330413  55.736254    0      4          7.0   
...   ..    ...        ...        ...        ...  ...    ...          ...   
4995  99      0          0 -22.787323 -19.553391    0   4995         32.0   
4996  99      0          0 -82.955598  11.663767    0   4996          4.0   
4997  99      0          0   0.929322  10.133367    0   4997         33.0   
4998  99      0          0 -16.414550   0.218805    0   4998         35.0   
4999  99      0          0  31.408102  -1.500168    0   4999         27.0   

      neighbor_100  
0               49  
1               48  
2               49  
3               44  
4               37  
...            ...  
4995            48  
4996            33  
4997            48  
4998            49  
4999            45  

[5000 rows x 9 columns]
```

NOTE: The output column will probably be a float because if there are no neighbors the value will be `NaN`, which cannot be represented with an `int`. However, if all rows have a neighbor, the dtype will be `int`.

Comment: This really works, it decreases the time needed from 2 and half hours to only 5 minutes, I only removed the drop_level(0) because it causes error, and dropped the key and index columns by drop(columns)
Thanks alot